# SQL query to retrieve results from an array of objects

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to find a SQL query to retrieve results if an id(for ex:21) is available in an array of objects [{id:21, verify:true}, {id:22, verify:false}] stored in Data column

Table A

```
Count|Data
E 1  |[{id:21, verify:true}, {id:22, verify:false}]

Select * from A where Data = 21
```

Comment: `... WHERE Data LIKE '%id:21,%'`?

Comment: You can use the built in MySQL `JSON_EXTRACT` function to search for your value if you fix the array saved in your table; the JSON value is invalid, its missing double quotes around the keys.